# Why does adding items to an ICollectionView from a UI thread in WPF result in a error, while it works fine with ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml, user-interface

I'm working on a WPF application and have encountered an issue with using ICollectionView to add items to a ObservableCollection. I have a IOPortsViewModel class that contains an ObservableCollection called DataPorts. In the constructor of this class, I create an instance of ICollectionView called CollectionDataPorts using CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DataPorts).

In my MainWindowViewModel class, I have a method called ReloadMainTreeViewSeparateThread() that creates some new MenuItem objects in a separate worker thread and adds them to an ObservableCollection called MenuItemsLeft which is defined on UI thread, trough Dispatcher. This works fine.

However, when I try to add items to CollectionDataPorts from the UI thread, I get the following error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.'
```

If I bind directly to DataPorts instead of CollectionDataPorts in my IOPortsView, everything works fine.

Here's my code for reference:

```
internal class IOPortsViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public IOPortsViewModel(object obj)
    {
        //Do something with obj

        CollectionDataPorts = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DataPorts);
    }

    private ICollectionView m_collectionDataPorts;

    public ICollectionView CollectionDataPorts
    {
        get => m_collectionDataPorts;
        set => SetProperty(ref m_collectionDataPorts, value);
    }
    
    private ObservableCollection<VMDataPorts> m_dataPorts;

    public ObservableCollection<VMDataPorts> DataPorts
    {
        get => m_dataPorts;
        set => SetProperty(ref m_dataPorts, value);
    }   
}
```

IOPortsView:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionDataPorts}">
```

```
internal class MainWindowViewModel : CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.ObservableObject
{
    ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItemsLeft = new();
    
    public void ReloadMainTreeViewSeparateThread()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { IsDialogLoadingOpen = true; });

            try
            {

//some heavy workload which is required to create ViewModels and MenuItems below
                object objFromBackend = Backend.GetSomeExpensiveObject();

                ObservableCollection<MenuItem> NewProcessedLeftMenuTree = new()
                {
                    new MenuItem ( new IOPortsViewModel(objFromBackend), "Title"),    
                };

                //Adding menuItems into UI thread which were created on this worker thread (Thread t)
                App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>
                {
                    foreach (MenuItem menuItem in NewProcessedLeftMenuTree)
                    {
                        MenuItemsLeft.Add(menuItem);
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (AggregateException aggrEx)
            {
                App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    IsDialogLogOpen = true;
                });
            }
            finally
            {
                App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    IsDialogLoadingOpen = false;
                });
            }
        });
        
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
    }

    private bool m_isDialogLoadingOpen;
    public bool IsDialogLoadingOpen
    {
        get => m_isDialogLoadingOpen;
        set => SetProperty(ref m_isDialogLoadingOpen, value);
    }

    private bool m_isDialogLogOpen;
    public bool IsDialogLogOpen
    {
        get => m_isDialogLogOpen;
        set => SetProperty(ref m_isDialogLogOpen, value);
    }
}
```

Why it works when I bind directly to ObservableCollection DataPorts in IOPortsView :
`<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DataPorts}">` ? So I can only change this in provided code and then it works. It only doesn't work when I bind to ICollectionView CollectionDataPort.

Why does this happen? Is this way of working with threads in a WPF application flawed? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

```
internal class MenuItem : CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.ObservableObject, IEnumerable<MenuItem>
{
    public PackIconKind? Icon { get; set; } = PackIconKind.None;
    public PackIconKind? IconStatus { get; } = PackIconKind.None;
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Children { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
    public MenuItem? Parent { get; set; }
    public ObservableObject ViewModel { get; }

    private bool m_isExpanded;

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get => m_isExpanded;
        set => SetProperty(ref m_isExpanded, value);
    }

    private bool m_isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => m_isSelected;
        set => SetProperty(ref m_isSelected, value);
    }

    private bool m_visibility = true;

    public bool Visibility
    {
        get => m_visibility;
        set => SetProperty(ref m_visibility, value);
    }

    public MenuItem(ObservableObject viewModel, string title, MenuItem? parent, PackIconKind icon)
        : this(viewModel, title, parent)
    {
        Icon = icon;
    }

    public MenuItem(ObservableObject? viewModel, string title, MenuItem? parent, ObservableCollection<MenuItem> children, PackIconKind icon)
    : this(viewModel, title, parent)
    {
        Children = children;
        Icon = icon;
    }

    public MenuItem(ObservableObject viewModel, string title, MenuItem? parent)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
        Parent = parent;

        //Title = title;
        if (viewModel is not null)
        {
            viewModel.Title = title;
        }
    }

    public void Add(MenuItem child)
    {
        Children.Add(child);
    }

    public ICommand SaveButtonCommand => new RelayCommand<object>(SaveButtonCommandFx, (object? x) => { return true; });

    private void SaveButtonCommandFx(object? obj)
    {
        if (ViewModel is RuleViewModel rule)
        {
            rule.ActiveCheck = !rule.ActiveCheck;
        }
    }

    public void SelectAndFocus()
    {
        var ancestors = this.GetAncestors();
        ancestors.ToList().ForEach(an => an.IsExpanded = true);
        IsSelected = true;
        IsExpanded = true;
    }


    public IEnumerator<MenuItem> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Children.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Children.GetEnumerator();
    }


    public IEnumerable<MenuItem> Descendants()
    {
        var nodes = new Stack<MenuItem>(new[] { this });
        while (nodes.Any())
        {
            MenuItem node = nodes.Pop();
            yield return node;
            foreach (var n in node.Children) nodes.Push(n);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<MenuItem> GetAncestors()
    {
        MenuItem parent = this.Parent;

        while (parent != null)
        {
            yield return parent;
            parent = parent.Parent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't show how you manipulate the collection view. Why is the first instruction of the Thread an operation enqueued to the Dispatcher (you could execute it before you start the thread. Threads should be started using Task.Run. What's the purpose of the thread when the only intensive work is posted back to the main thread? The PropertyChanged event is marshaled to the UI thread by the binding engine. No need to use the Dispatcher in order to set a property.

Comment: Why do you add MenuItem items to the collection you just created on the background thread using the dispatcher? Is this the MenuItem control?

Comment: @BionicCode when I add MenuItem to ICollectionView, either from code behind or from clicking on new Row to add new Item (new VMDataPorts) on DataGrid I get mentioned error. Regarding first instruction of the Thread which is enqueued to the Dispatcher, I agree on that that it could be done before starting thread. Regarding of purpose of using thread there, I'm sorry but I didn't mentioned that some heavy workload from backend code was there not only creation of ViewModels, I edited that in question.

Comment: @BionicCode MenuItem is not control but class which contains properties to which I bound to, I provided implementation in edit.

Comment: @BionicCode Anyway, I solved this problem by separating backend work into a different thread (creating all necessary objects required for creating all ViewModels) and work on the objects which the UI uses on UI thread (creating ViewModels, MenuItems, etc.). But now, I am interested in whether I could create ViewModels in a worker thread and then use those ViewModels in the UI thread without causing errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering occurs because the ICollectionView instance, CollectionDataPorts, is bound to the UI and therefore must be modified on the UI thread. In your code, you're trying to modify CollectionDataPorts from a separate worker thread, which is not allowed and results in the NotSupportedException you mentioned.

To resolve this issue, you should ensure that modifications to the CollectionDataPorts are performed on the UI thread. You can use the Dispatcher to invoke the modifications on the correct thread.

```
internal class IOPortsViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   public IOPortsViewModel()
  {
    DataPorts = new ObservableCollection<VMDataPorts>();
    CollectionDataPorts = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DataPorts);
  }

private ICollectionView m_collectionDataPorts;
public ICollectionView CollectionDataPorts
  {
    get => m_collectionDataPorts;
    set => SetProperty(ref m_collectionDataPorts, value);
  }

private ObservableCollection<VMDataPorts> m_dataPorts;
public ObservableCollection<VMDataPorts> DataPorts
  {
    get => m_dataPorts;
    set => SetProperty(ref m_dataPorts, value);
  }
}

internal class MainWindowViewModel : 
CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.ObservableObject
{
private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> menuItemsLeft = new();

public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItemsLeft
{
    get => menuItemsLeft;
    set => SetProperty(ref menuItemsLeft, value);
}

public void ReloadMainTreeViewSeparateThread()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { IsDialogLoadingOpen = true; });

        try
        {
            ObservableCollection<MenuItem> newProcessedLeftMenuTree = new()
            {
                new MenuItem(new IOPortsViewModel(), "Title"),
            };

            App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                foreach (MenuItem menuItem in newProcessedLeftMenuTree)
                {
                    MenuItemsLeft.Add(menuItem);
                }
              
                var ioPortsViewModel = newProcessedLeftMenuTree[0].ViewModel as IOPortsViewModel;
                if (ioPortsViewModel != null)
                {
                    ioPortsViewModel.CollectionDataPorts = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ioPortsViewModel.DataPorts);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (AggregateException aggrEx)
        {
            App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                IsDialogLogOpen = true;
            });
        }
        finally
        {
            App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                IsDialogLoadingOpen = false;
            });
        }
    });

    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}

}
```

I moved the initialization of the DataPorts collection to the constructor of IOPortsViewModel. Then, when creating the newProcessedLeftMenuTree, I access the IOPortsViewModel instance and update its CollectionDataPorts property on the UI thread.

By performing the modification on the UI thread, you avoid the NotSupportedException and ensure that the ICollectionView is updated correctly.

EDIT:

When you bind directly to the ObservableCollection DataPorts, the DataGrid receives notifications whenever items are added, removed, or modified in the collection. WPF's data binding system automatically handles these notifications and updates the UI accordingly.

On the other hand, when you bind to the ICollectionView CollectionDataPorts, the DataGrid is bound to a view of the collection rather than the collection itself. The ICollectionView provides sorting, filtering, and grouping capabilities, and it acts as an intermediary between the underlying data collection (DataPorts) and the UI.

In your original code, when you attempted to modify the CollectionDataPorts from a separate worker thread, you encountered the NotSupportedException because the ICollectionView was not designed to handle modifications from a different thread than the one it was created on (in this case, the UI thread).

To make it work with the ICollectionView, you need to ensure that any modifications to the underlying ObservableCollection (DataPorts) are performed on the UI thread. In the updated code, we used the Dispatcher.Invoke method to execute the modification of DataPorts and updating the CollectionDataPorts property on the UI thread.

Alternatively, if you only need basic functionality without sorting, filtering, or grouping, you can continue binding directly to the ObservableCollection DataPorts in your DataGrid and avoid the need for the ICollectionView.

Comment: Why it works when I bind directly to ObservableCollection DataPorts in IOPortsView : <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DataPorts}"> ? So I can only change this in mine provided code and then it works. It only doesn't work when I bind to ICollectionView CollectionDataPorts

Comment: I answered your question in an edit in the original answer.

Comment: This is not correct. In WPF you never bind to the collection. You always bind to collection views (implicitly). It's illegal to modify a collection view from another thread than the dispatcher thread that the binding was defined on the same way it is illegal to modify a collection. There is no difference.